# Looking for a search string in a file and using those lines for processing in TCL

Tags: tcl

To be more precise:

I need to be looking into a file abc.txt which has contents something like this:

```
files/f1/atmp.c        98   100  

files/f1/atmp1.c       89   100 

files/f1/atmp2.c  !!   75   100

files/f2/btmp.c        92   100

files/f2/btmp2.c  !!   85   100

files/f3/xtmp.c        92   100
```

The script needs to find "!!" and use those lines to print out the following as output:

```
atmp2.c  75

btmp2.c  85
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick.

```
set data {files/f1/atmp.c        98   100  
files/f1/atmp1.c       89   100 
files/f1/atmp2.c  !!   75   100
files/f2/btmp.c        92   100
files/f2/btmp2.c  !!   85   100
files/f3/xtmp.c        92   100}

set lines [split $data \n]
foreach line $lines {
  set match [regexp {(\S+)\s+!!\s+(\d+)} $line -> file num]
  if {$match} {puts "$file $num"}
}
```

Although regexp has a -all switch I don't think we can use it here as we only get the last match vars with -all

Answer (score 1):

If your file isn't huge, you can slurp the whole thing into memory, split the lines into a TCL list, and then iterate through the list looking for a match. For example:

```
set fh [open foo]
set lines [read $fh]
close $fh

set lines [split $lines "\n"]
foreach line $lines {
    if { [regexp {.*/(\S+\.c)\s*!!\s*(\d+)} $line match file data] } {
        puts "$file $data"
    }
}
```

This will successfully return just the lines with "!!" in them. With your posted corpus, the results are:

```
atmp2.c 75
btmp2.c 85
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be tempted in this case to exec to awk:

```
set output [exec awk {$2 == "!!" {print $1, $3}} abc.txt]
puts $output
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to combine the code that reads lines from the file with a regular expression that detects matching lines and extracts the relevant parts (a one-step process with `regexp`). The only tricky part is working out what *exactly* to use as the regular expression, so that you get exactly what you want. I'm going to guess that you're after the parts of the filenames after the `/`, that those filenames won't contain spaces, and that the number you're after is the entirety of the first digit sequence after the double exclamation. (Other formats are possible, some of which are easier to extract with other tools such as `scan`.) That would give us something like this:

```
set f [open abc.txt]
while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
    if {[regexp {([^\s/]+)\s+!!\s+(\d+)} $line -> name value]} {
        # Or do whatever you want with these
        puts "$name $value"
    }
}
close $f
```

(The `gets` command with two arguments returns the length of line read, or `-1` on failure. For *normal files* the only failure mode is EOF, so we can just terminate the loop when we get a negative value. Other kinds of channels can be more complex…)